# CakePHP 3 and form validation errors

Tags: forms, validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, validationerror

I use cakePHP 3 and I have a sign in form with Form->input().
If on purpose I make an error, this error doesn't whow up under the Form field. It doesn't appear anywhere.

My code is like this:

```
    $newUser = $this->Users->newEntity($this->request->data());

    if (!$this->Users->save($newUser)) {
        debug($newUser->errors());
        $this->Flash->error('Error');
        return;
    }
```

Debug show the errors, but shouldn't they appear under each form element automatically?

Comment: That's not enough information for anyone to be able to help you. You should at least show the errors and the form code, and ideally also the complete controller action code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok I found the error. 
I wasn't passing in Form->create the entiry but null. I did it like

```
$this->Form->create($entity...
```

and works nicely.