# CakePHP 3 show validation errors in template

Tags: php, cakephp

In CakePHP 3 I'm using my `UsersTable.php` model to validate that usernames are unique with the following:

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['username']), 'Username is already taken.');
    return $rules;
}
```

In my controller, `UsersController.php`, I can get the appropriate error message showing with `debug()`:

```
$user = $this->Users->newEntity();
// ...
debug($user->errors());
```

This will produce:

```
[
    'username' => [
        'Username is already taken.' => 'This value is already in use'
    ]
]
```

The only way I can think of sending this back to the template is by setting it in my Controller, for example `$this->set('errors', $user->errors())` and then displaying them in a template, for example

```
<?php if ($errors->username): ?>
<p class="error"><?= $errors->username; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is this the correct way to do it, or is there a shorter way? Do you manually have to send errors to the template? I'm sure Cake 2.x did all this automatically somehow?

*A similar question was asked here: [CakePHP 3 and form validation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936259/cakephp-3-and-form-validation-errors) but the answer given is about some other error in the code, even though it was accepted.*

Comment: Did you use form helper?

Comment: @RayannNayran Yes

Comment: You have to do like this in your form `$this->Form->create($user...` As if validation fails it will set error to the perticular field. Can you provide your Form code as will

Comment: @AmanRawat this is the correct solution. Please post as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Andy You can post the answer if you got the solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following advice from @AmanRawat the issue with my code was that the template `Users/add.ctp` should have the following:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($user) ?>
```

As opposed to `<?= $this->Form->create() ?>`. The difference being that this way the form helper will add the appropriate validation messages as it has an instance of `$this->Users->newEntity();` (specified in `UsersController.php`)

There is also a further amendment needed to get the validation message showing correctly in the model which is as follows (note the brackets are in a different place):

```
$rules->add($rules->isUnique(['username'], 'Username is already taken.'));
```